# Angularjs directive bind template manually

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

i am creating a mammoth table, when clicked on each cell of table a modal opens and some details about that cell is fetched from backend and displayed. This modal will have to be reused a lot so i am creating it as a angular directive.

```
.directive('ltInstanceStatus', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            instanceId: '=ltInstanceId'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            var getInstanceStatus = function() {
                // get Instance Status and pop modal
            };

            element.bind('click', getInstanceStatus);
        },
        templateUrl: '/assets/templates/instance_status.html'
    };
})
```

this works fine but i guess when the number of cells increase the page load will also increase. Is there a way such that i have a single piece of html for modal and reuse it again and again with changing data at same time maintain it in different folder.

Comment: You are using a `templateUrl`, so you already have a single piece of html?

Comment: templateUrl adds html in every cell of table

Answer (score 0):

this code check

```
.directive("chartDir",function(){

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<h2>Hello world!</h2> <div role="tabpanel" ng-transclude></div>',
    scope: { },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        elem.on('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {

                });
        });
    }
  }

});
```

click every cell in common function pass every unique value and call then apply return write common services and retrieve data.